# Which method type can i use to return a value in Java?

Tags: java, methods, void

I'm actually using a *void* method but i can't seem to return a value and i learned that void methods, as the name implies does not return value. Unfortunately, i can't use an int as my method has both numbers and letters stored in them. Is there a method type in java that i can use in replacement of *void*?

```
  void createtable()
    {
   int =noOfTables=5
   String tableName="employees";
    }
```

Comment: What do you actually *need* to return?

Comment: You are probably better of following some organized tutorial track ([like the ones Oracle offers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)) because what you're doing now looks like guessing your way through the language, and that will prove to be highly frustrating.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I want to return an int

Comment: @Afam then return an int and put int at place of void.

Comment: I keep getting the error message "void methods cannot return a value"

Answer (score 2):

You can use any return type you want — `int`, `String`, `Map`, etc.

If you need to return complex information (like both an `int` and a `String`), you'll want to choose or create an appropriate class for that, and return an instance of that class.

For example:

```
class TableInfo {
    private int noOfTables;
    private String tableName;

    TableInfo(int no, String name) {
        this.noOfTables = no;
        this.tableName = name;
    }

    // ...accessors like getNoOfTables and such here...
}
```

Then:

```
TableInfo createtable()
{
    int noOfTables = 5;
    String tableName = "employees";
    return new TableInfo(noOfTables, tableName);
}
```